# Is There a Unitary Transformation Which Maps Non-Orthogonal Vectors into 'Uniform' Vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, hadamard-matrices

I would like to find a unitary matrix $U$ which maps normalised vectors $\mathbf{v}^{(i)}$ from the set:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{V} = \Bigg\{
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0\\
0
\\
\vdots
\end{pmatrix},
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1\\
0
\\
\vdots
\end{pmatrix},
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1\\
1
\\
\vdots
\end{pmatrix},
\ldots \Bigg\}
\end{equation}
into vectors $\mathbf{u}^{(i)} = U\mathbf{v}^{(i)}$ such that the magnitude of the elements of each $\mathbf{u}^{(i)}$ are equal i.e $|{\mathbf{u}^{(i)}}_j|= |{\mathbf{u}^{(k)}}_l| \,\, \forall \,\, i,j,k,l$.

If no such $U$ exists then is there a larger unitary which acts on the vectors $\mathbf{v}^{(i)}$ embedded in a larger vector-space as $\mathbf{v}^{(i)}\oplus \mathbf{0}$ ?

It is easy to see that if $\mathcal{V}= \big\{\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\end{pmatrix}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1\\
\end{pmatrix} \big\}$  then $U =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & i\\ i & 1  \end{pmatrix}$ satisfies the above criteria. Does this generalise to more than two dimensions? If not, I would like to know why.

I have tried to use various complex Hadamards to no avail. I've also tried using the cosine-sine decomposition to construct a unitary on $\mathbf{v}^{(i)}\oplus \mathbf{0}$ but with no success.

Thanks in advance,
Patrick.

**Update:**
I have been able to numerically find a three dimensional unitary which acts on $\mathbf{v}^{(1)},\,\mathbf{v}^{(2)}$ and $\mathbf{v}^{(3)}$ satisfying the criteria. I have tried numerically to solve the four dimensional case and have come very close but not solved it exactly (to numerical precision).

The only structure in the 3D case I observed is that the magnitude of the elements in the first column are all equal. This is obviously necessary in hindsight since $\mathbf{v}^1$ needs to be spread out uniformly.